# Excel 3D bar graph: column height does not match vertical axis value on back wall

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

Why does the following data result in a bar graph in which the bars do not meet the gridline on the y axis? See the following two bar graphs as examples.

```
   X  y
A  1  1
B  2  2
```

[image: 3D graph 1]

[image: 3D graph 2]

Answer (score 2):

It's an optical illusion.  Notice that the columns are not tight against the back wall.  The fact that you can see the top surface means that you are "looking down" at the columns, so you're seeing the gridlines on the back wall "behind" the columns.  If you extend the top side edge back the distance the columns are from the wall, they will meet the grid line.

The illusion is even worse on the left side.  The perspective is not only looking down, but to the left (you can see the right side of the columns).  On the back wall, left/right doesn't affect anything.  But on the side wall, your perception is affected by the perspective in both directions.  If you extend the front edges the distance to the side wall, you will see that it intersects the grid lines, only not at the location you visually expected.

Comment: Great answer, and this is why 3-d charts should never be used!  Data is hard enough to interpret without doing extra mental gymnastics to compensate for extra-dimensional chart junk.